# "The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type"

Tags: java, static, compilation, program-entry-point

```
class Perkusja {
  boolean talerze = true;
  boolean beben = true;

  void zagrajNaBebnie() {
    System.out.println("bam, bam, baaaa-am-am");
  }
  void zagrajNaTalerzach() {
    System.out.println("brzdęk, brzbrzrzdęęk");
  }
  class PerkusjaTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Perkusja p = new Perkusja();
    }
  }
}
```

Hello! I'm new to stackoverflow so please forgive me my atrocious editing.

I'm new to Java and i can't figure out where exactly the issue lies and what's the problem.
I get the following error on the line
`public static void main(String[]args)`:

> The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

I'm using eclipse and i'm doing some simple java exercises. I googled the problem but the answers are usually related to much more complex pieces of code.

How do i fix it and what's the cause of the following error? I'd be grateful for an explanation on this particular example.

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are declaring your main method in `PerkusjaTester` which is an inner class of `Perkusja`. That is forbidden.

You should declare your test class outside of class `Perkusja`

Note : `PerkusjaTester` is an inner class, not a static nested class. That is why `PerkusjaTester` is not a static type. As mentionned by Jon Skeet, you could also add the keyword `static` on class `PerkusjaTester`.

Comment: Yeah declaring as static nested class enables you to use static methods, but you can also easily just remove the static modifier to the method signature and invoke it from the outer class's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This code cannot work since, conceptually, an instance of an `Perkusja` would have to be declared in advance of `main` being called.

This is because the inner class `PerkusjaTester` is **not** marked as static.

The best fix for you is to write `static class PerkusjaTester {`.

Then `main` is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The main method in `PerkusjaTester` is an inner class of `Perkusja` which is forbidden. Considering you are new to this the simple answer I can give is, remove the last curly bracket and put it above `class PerkusjaTester`, the error will be removed.