# How to count similar rows in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, count

I have an Arraylist list1 of type SearchList which is my pojo class. I want to find number of similar rows and their frequency occuring in list1..
How do I achieve this?

My code:

```
List<SearchList> list1= new ArrayList<SearchList>();;
SearchList sList = new SearchList();
 for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
        sList.setArea(list.get(k).getArea());
        sList.setLocation(list.get(k).getLocation());
        list1.add(sList);       
}
```

I have done this for counting frequency but doesn't execute:

```
 Set<SearchList> uniqueSet = new HashSet<SearchList>(list1);
     for (SearchList temp : uniqueSet) {
            System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list1, temp));
     }
```

Comment: The main problem I can see is that you are adding the same instance of `SearchList` to `list1` many times (you should add a new instance each time). What do you mean by `doesn't execute`?

Comment: your SearchList has hashCode and equals overriden?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: " adding the same instance of SearchList to list1 many times " means? for loop is not excecuting

Comment: how is list defined?

Comment: I'm not getting any error..but this solution isn't working either..

Comment: the statement "System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list1, 
temp));" didn't execute even once.. @markus list is another arraylist defined globally

Comment: the set is empty so the code within the loop wont execute check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SearchList> list1= new ArrayList<SearchList>(); //list1 is empty
```

`list1` is empty so the code with in the for loop:

```
for (SearchList temp : uniqueSet) {
            System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list1, 
temp));
        }
```

would not execute (`uniqueSet` must have at least one element in order the loop code to be executed) as the set will also be empty:

```
 Set<SearchList> uniqueSet = new HashSet<SearchList>(list1); // set is empty
```

Comment: but list1 is not empty

Comment: what is the size of `list` ?

Comment: the size of list is dynamic..but its not empty

Comment: If it is not empty it would have been executed at least once.

Comment: is there any other way to find frequency of similar rows?

Comment: Yes, as there are many ways to skin a cat! but please tell me `list` is empty

Comment: oh  I replaced System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list1, temp)); with statement int aa = Collections.frequency(list1, temp);   and I got aa=1 two times when I entered 2 similar items

Comment: lets take this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92722/discussion-between-degen-sharew-and-sheena-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the equals() method on SearchList, since Collections.frequency() calls this method, and be sure that "uniqueSet" is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

you should do the following:

- make sure there are entries in your globally defined list (change its name to something less misleading btw.)
- make sure you add new instances of SearchList to your list1. At the moment you are adding the same SearchList-Object over and over to your list1. Therefore if you call setArea or setLocation on your sList Object all your lsit entries will change their values. The list entry is just a reference pointing at the real object in memory.
- make sure you supply proper equals() and hashcode() implementations for your SearchList class. 
  check this Link on equals() and hashcode(): [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `distinct` the row based on value of both **area** and **location** value then with `Java 8` [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), it is as simple as:

```
int countSimilar = (int) searchListList.stream().distinct().count();
```

Or, if distinctness of row depends on value of **area** only:

```
int countSimilarByArea = searchListList
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<SearchList>((
                                p1, p2) -> p1.getArea().compareTo(p2.getArea()))))
                .size();
```

Or, if distinctness of row depends on value of **location** only:

```
int countSimilarByLocation = searchListList
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<SearchList>((
                                p1, p2) -> p1.getLocation().compareTo(
                                p2.getLocation())))).size();
```

Usage:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

final class SearchList {
    private final String area;
    private final String location;

    public SearchList(String area, String location) {
        this.area = area;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchList [area=" + area + ", location=" + location + "]";
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((area == null) ? 0 : area.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((location == null) ? 0 : location.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SearchList other = (SearchList) obj;
        if (area == null) {
            if (other.area != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!area.equals(other.area))
            return false;
        if (location == null) {
            if (other.location != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!location.equals(other.location))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class CountSimilar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SearchList> searchListList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchListList.add(new SearchList("A", "India"));
        searchListList.add(new SearchList("B", "India"));
        searchListList.add(new SearchList("A", "India"));
        searchListList.add(new SearchList("A", "USA"));
        searchListList.add(new SearchList("A", "USA"));

        int countSimilar = (int) searchListList.stream().distinct().count();

        System.out.println(countSimilar);

        int countSimilarByArea = searchListList
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<SearchList>((
                                p1, p2) -> p1.getArea().compareTo(p2.getArea()))))
                .size();
        System.out.println(countSimilarByArea);

        int countSimilarByLocation = searchListList
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<SearchList>((
                                p1, p2) -> p1.getLocation().compareTo(
                                p2.getLocation())))).size();

        System.out.println(countSimilarByLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error: "The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type"

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787063/the-method-main-cannot-be-declared-static-static-methods-can-only-be-declared