# Need to input value into field, check result, and then add one character in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

This is the first time I have ever coded, so excuse my ignorance.

I have the following Selenium code that is for online ordering from a restaurant. At the end, it is putting a value into a field, checking and printing the result, then what I need to do is change the original input, and do it again. So I need a loop. I think.

```
package Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\testuser\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        driver.get("onlineorder.com");
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement startorder = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#startOrder_148"));
        startorder.click();
        Thread.sleep(4500);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement selectfood = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"NEW! Steak Po'boy (670 cal)\")]"));
        selectfood.click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        WebElement additem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#addItemToOrder"));
        additem.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement checkout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Checkout')]"));
        checkout.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#logonCheckoutBtn"));
        loginbutton.click();
        Thread.sleep(3500);

        //WebElement click5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"));
        //action.click(click5).perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loginPassword")).sendKeys("password");

        WebElement loginbutton2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loginButton"));
        loginbutton2.click();
        Thread.sleep(5500);

        WebElement paymenttype = driver.findElement(By.id("selectPaymentType"));
        Select payment=new Select(paymenttype);
        payment.selectByIndex(3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("numberchecker")).sendKeys("1000");
        WebElement checkbalance = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix ng-scope']//div[@class='clearfix']//a[@class='numberchecker btn'][contains(text(),'Check balance')]"));
        checkbalance.click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);

        for(WebElement link:driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='popup_message ng-binding']")))

        {
            System.out.println(link.getText());

        }

        WebElement okaybalance = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#btnPopupOk"));
        okaybalance.click();
```

Everything works fine until here. What I need to do is go back and change the original input value (1000) by 1 to 1001. The error I get for getInputNumber is "AnnotationName expected after this token". Also, the name of the class "addnumber" gives error "Illegal modifier, only abstract or final is permitted". "class" gives error "syntax error, @ expected".

```
        public class addnumber() {
                private static float inputNumber= 1000f;

                public static float getInputNumber() {
                    return inputNumber+ 1.0f;
                }
            }


        Thread.sleep(4000);

        //driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: first piece of code does not use second piece of code, so it's hard to say, but my guess is you tried to declare class `Sample` inside some other class. In which case either `Sample` must be static, or it cannot contain static variables. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787063/the-method-main-cannot-be-declared-static-static-methods-can-only-be-declared

Answer (score 1):

You have declared class wrongly. It should be

```
public class Sample{

//Then the stuff you want to do.


}
```

To access this class you need to create outer class object and them inner
Like this.

```
Outer d=new Outer();
d.Sample obj=new d.Sample();
```

But as you have declared member static for sample class you can just call them using classname.